# The quickest way to find information in the tree data structure.

Tags: java, tree, structure

Given a tree structure that consist of 1..n nested nodes and represented as set of related entity objects that are mapped to a DB using JPA/Hibernate. And, given an input of 100k-1m records. What would be a quickest way to process all records one-by-one against this tree and lockup relevant information for each record form the tree. During the look up different filtration rules will apply and the depth of a node will be taken into consideration.

I understand that there are probably a lot of things that should be taken into account before one discusses a potential approach to a problem  (such as the tree structure, what kind of information needs to be looked up and so on). However, I'm only looking for a generic description/guidance of possible approaches on how to tackle similar tasks and maybe a few words as to what are the pros/cons of a given approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably OK to read every entry and put it into a Java Map of child -> parent (as long as each entry is small). You can then get the depth of a given entity by following these relationships to the root, counting them as you go.

The downside is it doesn't scale to bajillions of entries, but a million is probably OK. If this is for batch processing it should be plenty fast enough.